# why virtual is allowed while implementing the interface methods?

Tags: c#, interface, methods, virtual

I have one specific query with the interfaces.

By default interface methods are abstract and virtual so if we implement that interface and gives definition in the class we actually override that method but when we mark the method as a virtual again in the implementing class why the compiler is not considering that we are actually trying to hide the original interface virtual method.

Like if we have a virtual method in the base class and derived class again marked the method as virtual in that case compiler gives the warning that you are hiding the base class method so use new if you are intentionally hiding the base class method.

```cs
public interface ITestInterface
{
    void virtualmethod(); // this method is by default virtual. 
}
```

```cs
public class TestInterface :ITestInterface
{
   public virtual void virtualmethod()
   {
    // Now compiler should consider that i am actually hiding the interface virtual method.
   }
}
```

if you build the above code for interface and open in ILDASM you will see the code like this:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual
         instance void virtualmethod() cil managed
{
}//end of method ITestInterface::virtualmethod
```

Comment: instead of virtual, assuming that methods in interface is abstract by default, makes more sense.

Comment: yes that fine but once the complier attach virtual with the method and you are again putting virtual while implementing the method then complier should say that you are hiding the original declaration.

Comment: I understand you, interface methods are virtual in the sense they are dynamically bound. C# is intentionally hiding this by making "non-virtual" implementation a virtual final internally (and allowing the use of virtual as a way to indicate you may want to continue overriding).

Answer (score 76):

Methods that are implemented from an interface are *not* virtual by default.  You are merely providing an implementation of the contract defined in the interface definition.  By marking the method as `virtual`, you are allowing derived classes to provide additional or separate implementation while still honoring the contract as defined.

Consider this example:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string Speak();
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Speak()
    {
        return "Bark!";
    }
}
```

The `Dog` class is *implementing* the interface by providing an implementation of the contract `IAnimal`.  There are no virtual methods here and no overriding.

Now consider this example:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string Speak();
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public virtual string Speak()
    {
        return "Bark!";
    }
}

class GoldenRetriever : Dog
{
    public override string Speak()
    {
        return "I am a golden retriever who says " 
                   + base.Speak();
    }
}
```

Now the `Dog` class has declared `Speak` to be `virtual` which allows derived classes to provide an additional or new implementation.  This does not break the contract with `IAnimal` as any call to the `Speak` method still returns a string.

Ok, one last example.  Remember that interfaces don't require an implementation - they only require that the contract is satisfied.  This means that the interface only cares that a member exists in the implementing class that has a matching signature.  This means that we could also do this:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string Speak();
}

abstract class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public abstract string Speak();
}

class GoldenRetriever : Dog
{
    public override string Speak()
    {
        return "I am a golden retriever";
    }
}
```

Notice now that the `Dog` class provides no implementation at all for `Speak` yet has satisfied the requirements of the contract.

Interfaces are also inherited from class to class so in all the examples above both `Dog` and `GoldenRetriever` implement the `IAnimal` interface.  Neither class *hide* the `Speak` method - both classes *implement* it.

---

Ok, I think your confusion may be coming from the fact that the virtual method is defined in an interface, not a class.  Here is the IL for the interface I defined above:

```
.class private interface abstract auto ansi IAnimal
{
    .method public hidebysig newslot abstract 
        virtual instance string Speak() cil managed
    {
    }
}
```

While you are correct that the method is defined as `virtual` you also need to notice that the type here is designated as an `interface`.  This is purely an implementation detail of the MSIL generated by Microsoft's C# compiler - another compiler could easily generate different code as long as semantically it provided the same result.

The important thing here is this: even though the method is declared as `virtual` in the interface that does not mean that it is the same thing as a `virtual` method declared in class.

Comment: Kindly check the question again as i added the IL code for the same

Comment: .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance void virtualmethod() cil managed { }//end of method ITestInterface::virtualmethod

Answer (score 4):

Interface is not Base Class, so implementation methods are not overriden. Interface only declares the methods, Interface methods are not virtual by default, infact interfaces only declare the methods that are available on the class that implements that interface.

**Declaration can not be virtual.**

**Implementation can or cannot be virtual that is completely dependent on the implementer's logic.**

Comment: Interfaces are just a type with the virtual methods so the behaviour should be same as classes.

Comment: @Mohit - This is not entirely true.  Yes they are just another type but they are an *interface* type which makes all the difference.  Interfaces and classes are different at the IL level.

Answer (score 4):

There is a mix-up of the term 'virtual' here, between IL and C#.
They do not completely correspond. Virtual in the IL sense means "it's called indirect" via a VMT(virtual method table), that is about the same mechanism for class overriding and interface implementation.
In the IL sense, an interface member must be marked virtual - there is no way around.
But if you look in the implementation, it's marked as 'virtual final'. That is something you cannot achieve in C#. 'Final' means, it cannot be overriden. It does not become virtual in the meaning of C#, unless you declare it manually as 'virtual' or 'abstract' in C#.

The implicit interface implementation of C# (it doesn't exist in VB.NET or IL) is quiet powerful. It does attach the Method of the implementing class, that matches in Name-Parameters-ReturnValue (the Signature, or SigAndName in the IL wording).
This includes using base class implementations for the methods.

```
public interface ITest
{
    double MethodC(double a, double b, double c, double d);
}

internal class BaseClass
{
    public double MethodC(double a, double b, double c, double d)
    {
        return a+b+c+d;
    }
}

internal class OtherClass : BaseClass , ITest 
{
}
```

This actually works fine.
But C# is doing a Trick here, Cause you use the BaseClass.MethodC as an interface implementation, it's marked as final virtual in the BaseClass.
Yes, the way how BaseClass is implemented, depends on how BaseClass is used.
BaseClass.MethodC is modified, cause it's used to implement ITest.MethodC in a derived class. This even works over file and project boundaries, as long as the source code of BaseClass is in the same solution.

So the output of the compilation of a project, is not the same, if you compile it by itself, or in a big solution together with other products. This is quiet noticable.

If the source code of BaseClass is not available, if you just linked into a DLL, then C# will generate a Wrapper to use the BaseClass implementation.
It will actually do this:

```
internal class OtherClass : BaseClass , ITest 
{
    double ITest.MethodC(double a, double b, double c, double d)
    {
        return base.MethodC(a, b, c, d)
    }
}
```

This is done in secret, but it's absolutely necessary to have a method marked as virtual in the IL sense.

Comment: One correction: C# has always had `sealed` which achieves the same result for `override` methods in child classes.