# What effect does the `virtual` modifier have on an interface member?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Say I have an interface like `interface IThing { virtual string A => "A"; }`. What effect does the `virtual` keyword have on implementing types here? Surprisingly, I couldn't find anything regarding this on either SO, `dotnet` GitHub pages and discussions, nor on `learn.microsoft.com`, possibly buried under all the unrelated content where the words `interface` and `virtual` appear in any combination. From my quick testing it doesn't appear to have any sensible effect. My intuition tells me to expect from the implementing classes' hierarchy to have been introduced the given virtual members, as if the base implementing class has declared them itself, but it's not the case.

For example:

```cs
class Thing: IThing
{   
}   
    
class Thing2: Thing
{
    override public string A => "!"; // ERROR: No suitable method found to override.
}
```

If I declare the `A` property on `Thing`, but do not declare it explicitly as virtual, it still won't compile. I also have the freedom apparently to just define them w/o the modifier despite it being present in the interface and it compiles. And code using `IThing` only sees the default implementation of `A` regardless of what I do unless the class implements the interface directly and not through inheritance in this setup.

Can somebody clarify the use of the `virtual` modifier on interface members? I use the latest stable language version of C#.

Comment: Methods implementing an interface are not `virtual` by default (see: [why virtual is allowed while implementing the interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470446/why-virtual-is-allowed-while-implementing-the-interface-methods)). But if they are marked as `virtual` in the interface then do become such.

Comment: @wohlstad the thing here is that `Thing` does not have implementation for `IThing.A` at all =)

Comment: @GuruStron isn't that because the interface contains a default implementation ? Or do you mean that an interface method with a default implementation is always virtual by default (but can tagged as such anyway for verbosity) ? I'm not sure I understand this point in your answer.

Comment: @wohlstad _"isn't that because the interface contains a default implementation"_ - yes, exactly and I would argue that this makes the question a bit different compared to one you have linked.

Comment: Now I understand. Good to know (I'm not an expert in C#). +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following:

```
interface IThing { virtual string A => "A"; }
```

Is the so called [default interface method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods) and virtual as far as I can see actually does nothing because:

> The `virtual` modifier may be used on a function member that would otherwise be implicitly `virtual`

I.e. it just an explicit declaration of the fact that **interface** method is virtual since the language team decided to not restrict such things.

See also the [Virtual Modifier vs Sealed Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#virtual-modifier-vs-sealed-modifier) part of the spec:

> Decisions: Made in the LDM 2017-04-05:
>
> - non-`virtual` should be explicitly expressed through `sealed` or `private`.
> - `sealed` is the keyword to make interface instance members with bodies non-`virtual`
> - We want to allow all modifiers in interfaces
> - ...

Note that default implemented `IThing.A` is not part of the `Thing`, hence you can't do `new Thing().A`, you need to cast to the interface first.

If you want to override the `IThing.A` in the `Thing2` then you can implement the interface directly:

```
class Thing2 : Thing, IThing
{
     public string A => "!"; 
}

Console.WriteLine(((IThing)new Thing()).A); // Prints "A"
Console.WriteLine(((IThing)new Thing2()).A); // Prints "!"
```

Another way would be declaring `public virtual string A` in the `Thing` so your current code for `Thing2` works:

```
class Thing : IThing
{
    public virtual string A => "A";
}   
    
class Thing2 : Thing
{
    public override string A => "!"; 
}
```

To understand meaning of `sealed`/`virtual` identifiers in interfaces you can create a second interface:

```
interface IThing {  string A => "A"; }
interface IThing2 : IThing {  string IThing.A => "B"; }
class Thing : IThing2 {}

Console.WriteLine(((IThing)new Thing()).A); // Prints "B"
```

While if you declare `IThing.A` as `sealed` then `IThing2` will not compile:

```cs
interface IThing { sealed string A => "A"; }

interface IThing2 : IThing
{
    // Does not compile:
    // string IThing.A => "B";
}

class AntoherThing : IThing
{
    // Does not compile too:
    string IThing.A => "B";
}
```

Also check out the [why virtual is allowed while implementing the interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4470446/2501279) linked by [wohlstad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18519921/wohlstad) in the comments.

Comment: Explicitly declaring the base class member has unfortunate side effect of not being able to use the default implementation from the interface, right?

Comment: @ZzZombo _"Explicitly declaring the base class member"_ - if by explicit declaration you mean the snippet with `Thing` class having `A` defined then you should understand that without this there is no "implicit" `A` in the `Thing` (i.e. `typeof(Thing).GetProperties().Length` will result in `0`). Also not sure what do you mean by "fallback", but if I understand correctly - then no. And checko out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62334580/2501279 maybe it will be useful.

Comment: Brilliant answer! I initially closed this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60640745/87698, but your answer actually gives a concrete example where virtual and sealed make a difference, so I reverted that.

Comment: BTW, you [don't need to use a second interface](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8WYxCv) to see the difference.

Comment: @Heinzi yes, encountered this also, will add that to answer. Thank you!

Comment: @GuruStron: I had edited the comment to make it clearer. P. S.: I mean it would be unfortunate not to be able to reuse the default implementation, making having it at all moot.